# displaying most rated restaurants in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this table reviews thats stores user's reviews with restaurants id.This is the store function for reviews.i need it to save the average rating and store it in the rating count column

```
    $review = new Review;

    $review->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $review->restaurant_id = $request->get('restaurant_id');
    $review->value = $request->input('value');
    $review->rating = $request->input('rating'); 
    $avgRating = $review->avg('rating');
    $review->rating_count = round($avgRating, 1);

    $review->save();
```

But this saves the rating value for each restaurant, it doesn't calculate the rating and increment it:

[image]

Help please, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't store the average review rating on every record of your review table. Instead you can get that value through a query, I'm assuming that a `Restaurant` has many `Review`s:

#### Restaurant.php

```
public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Review::class);
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
public function myCoolFunction()
{
    $restaurant = Restaurant::with('reviews')->find(1);

    $avg = $restaurant->reviews->avg('rating'); // '4.67' for example
}
```

Of course, you could define this computed value in your model for an easier access:

#### Restaurant.php

```
// ...

public function getAvgRatingAttribute()
{
    return $this->reviews()->avg('rating');
}
```

So now in your controller and view:

```
public function myCoolFunction()
{
    $restaurant = Restaurant::find(1);

    return view('my_view')->with('restaurant', $restaurant);
}
```

Then:

```
<p>{{ $restaurant->avg_rating }}</p>
```

Comment: the thing is i want this value stored so that i can write a query to compute most rated restaurants

Comment: @nerdme but it doens't make sense. This is why: The last record ('rating_count') will be the only accurate one, all of the other will show pass data. So, you are storing data that isn't gonna be accurate. Also, you say that you wan to compute the most rated restaurants.. this can also be achieved using eloquent.

Comment: how can you achieve this in eloquent

Comment: @nerdme check [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/orderby-computed-related-attribute).

Answer (score 0):

You could do the calculation on the collection of all `reviews` in PHP:

```php
// Restaurant.php

class Restaurant
{
    public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Review');
    }

    public function avgRating()
    {
        return $this->reviews->avg('rating');
    }
}
```

Using the Eloquent relationship between the two database tables, use the [`avg()` function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-average) to calculate the average review, passing in the column to be averaged.

Then in your code, you can call `$restaurant->avgRating()`.  Be warned that each call will perform a SQL query that returns all rows and then averages the results, so this method won't scale well for large datasets.

Comment: how do i store this value so as to to perfom SQL queries for the most rated?